# How to initialize and use an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm doing some c# homework and these are the instructions:

> Create a new project called FunWithArrays.
>
> Add a class called Game and make sure it is public. Game should have a
>   public 2 dimensional byte array of size 5 x 5 called BingoCard.
>   BingoCard should be initialized in the constructor for the Game class.
>   There should also be a public string property called PlayerName in the
>   Game class. The same constructor mentioned above should receive a
>   string to initialize the player's name.
>
> Back in the main method create a single dimension Game array of size
>   3. Add three new games using the names "Beth", "Chris", and "Don". Add a Random object to the main method.
>
> Pass the Game array and Random object to a static method called
>   "InitilizeArray." Use a foreach loop to iterate through the games.
>   Inside the foreachloop, use nested for loops to assign a random byte
>   value to each of the 25 elements in the array. (hint: use something
>   like (byte)rand.next() to have the Random object return a byte. Make
>   sure that the random byte range is 1 to 75.
>
> Then, from the main method, pass the game array to a static method
>   called "DisplayArray." Then use foreach and for loops as before to
>   print out each player and that player's bingo card. The cards should
>   be displayed in a table of 5 x 5 in the console.

So far, I'm stuck in the 3rd paragraph.

In the first paragraph I made a class which seems right:

```
public class Game
{
    public Game() { }

    public Game (string pN)
    {
        PlayerName = pN;
        byte[,] BingoCard = new byte[5, 5];
    }

    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
}
```

And for the second paragraph, in my main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int GameSize = 3;

    Random rand = new Random();
    Game[] gameArray = new Game[GameSize];

    Game game1 = new Game("Chris");
    Game game2 = new Game("Beth");
    Game game3 = new Game("Don");

    InitializeArray(gameArray[], rand);
}
```

I'm not sure if I did the "create three new games" right, but I think it is.

Now I'm having problems with the third paragraph, should I be passing each new game (game1, game2, game3) to the gameArray and then iterate through each game with a foreach loop such as:

```
foreach (var game in g)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            game[row, col] = (byte)r.Next();
        }
    }
}
```

How should I add three new games and initialize them?

Comment: What does your debugging say? what are the values of your last snippet?

Comment: *Am I doing this correctly?* is not a concrete question.

Comment: You have too many games. You have the array of games then 3 more with names. The ones in the array should be named

Comment: I have one error in my for loop in game[row,col] that I cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression type game. So I'm currently trying to solve that.

Comment: Edited question to better reflect problem

Comment: To start with `BingoCard` is just a local variable to the constructor.  It seems like it should be either a field or property.  Second you don't add the games to your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your instructions:

> Game should have a **public** 2 dimensional byte array of size 5 x 5 called BingoCard.

But in your class you've declared the byte array inside the constructor. This means that when the class is created and the constructor is called, a byte array is created. Then, in the next line when the constructor ends, the byte array is no longer available.

What you should do is create it as a public property, just as you did with `PlayerName`:

```
public class Game
{
    // Public properties
    public byte[,] BingoCard = new byte[5, 5];
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }

    // Constructors
    public Game() { }

    public Game(string pN)
    {
        PlayerName = pN;            
    }
}
```

Now it will be accessible to your program.

---

> ...create a single dimension Game array of size 3. Add three new games using the names "Beth", "Chris", and "Don"

While you have created 3 games, you haven't added them to the array. You can do this using indexes:

```
Game[] gameArray = new Game[GameSize];

gameArray[0] = new Game("Chris");
gameArray[1] = new Game("Beth");
gameArray[2] = new Game("Don");
```

---

And now you can loop through the game array and can reference `game.BingoCard` to add items to the multidimensional array of each `Game` object:

```
foreach (var game in gameArray)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            game.BingoCard[row, col] = (byte)r.Next();
        }
    }
}
```

However you still have some work to do...

> Make sure that the random byte range is 1 to 75.

Comment: Thank you! I initially had the BingoCard outside of the constructor, but misunderstood the instruction to mean that it should be created inside the constructor. And for creating the games, I'm understanding that the element is now a new object of the class game?

Comment: Yes. It's a shorter way of doing something like: `Game game1 = new Game("Chris"); gameArray[0] = game1;`, which also works just fine.

Comment: I was also having trouble with the game[row,col], giving me an error of cannot apply indexing to an expression of type Game. I see that this is fixed by adding .BingoCard to it. Is it correct that this is because rather than accessing and writing to the games, adding .BingoCard means that we are accessing that games BingoCard property thus making it valid? I apologize if this sounds gibberish.

Comment: Yep. BingoCard is now a public property of Game, so you can add items  to it.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for the help, I was struggling with understanding arrays as I just started learning and using them.

Comment: No problem. You just about had it so I thought it should be ok to post an answer. Normally homework questions only get "hints".